# Why doesn't this work (can't assign the operator) in Python

Tags: python, assign

It says that it can't assign the operator.
Why doesn't this work?

```
print ("Welkom")
print ("Voer het huidige bedrag op uw rekening in")
currentbank = input ("huidige bedrag:€")
print ("Hoeveel wil je erafhalen")
minusbank = input ("min:€")
print ("Je hebt als je dit doet:")
afterbank = false 
afterbank = currentbank - minusbank
print ("Dankjewel dat je dit programma gebruikt hebt")
```

"afterbank = currentbank - minusbank" has this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Please do include the full traceback when you have a problem.

Comment: `currentbank-minusbank=afterbank` What are you trying to do here? My guess is you wanted to do `afterbank=currentbank-minusbank`, and then `afterbank=False` is not needed at all. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`false` should be spelled `False` (capital `F`).

The intent behind `currentbank-minusbank=afterbank` is unclear to me, but it is not valid code.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

```
afterbank=false
```

You should spell it as `False`. In Python `True` and `False` are spelled with capitals.

The following line also won't work (it's incorrect):

```
currentbank-minusbank=afterbank
```

I think you meant:

```
afterbank = currentbank - minusbank
```

which means you subtract `minusbank` from `currentbank` and you store the result in `afterbank`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use assignment on an expression:

```
currentbank-minusbank=afterbank
```

This doesn't work; there is no name to assign *to* here. Perhaps you wanted to test for equality here?

```
currentbank - minusbank == afterbank
```

Now you have a valid expression, but the result (`True` or `False`) is ignored.

Your editor is also showing that you are using a name you didn't define; `false` is seen as a name, not the value `False`, so it is warning you that a `NameError` will likely be raised there.

I **think** you wanted to show the result of the sum:

```
afterbank = currentbank - minusbank
print("Nu heb je", afterbank, "over")
```